# SQL query to show orders with same id in same line but its own UF field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a statments query that has to display all data with same BT_ID in one line but under a different UF field. For example I have multiple orders with the same BT_ID and need to show each Invoice_reference number in its own UF field.
However I don't get all the data over to my UF fields. Many field are that shold not be blank are blank. Any help is appriciated, Thank you:

```
DECLARE
@OrgCode varchar(5), @FromDate varchar(15)


Set @OrgCode = 'iho' Set @FromDate = '08/23/2013'


SELECT     Invoice.BT_ID,  
           Name.COMPANY, 
           Name.COMPANY_RECORD, 
           Name.COMPANY_SORT, 
           Name.LAST_FIRST, 
           Name.FULL_NAME, 
           Name_Address.PURPOSE, 
           Name.TITLE, 
           Name_Address.FULL_ADDRESS, 
           Invoice.INSTALL_BILL_DATE, 
           Org_Control.OrgName, 
           Org_Control.InvoiceAddress, 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR, Invoice.INVOICE_DATE, 101)AS INVOICE_DATE, 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR, Trans.TRANSACTION_DATE, 101)AS TRANSACTION_DATE, 
           Trans.POSTED,
           Invoice.CUSTOMER_REFERENCE, 
           Invoice.INVOICE_TYPE, 
           Org_Control.OrgCode, 
           Name.EMAIL,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 1  THEN '</td>'+ cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF6,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 2  THEN '<td>' + cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF7,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 3  THEN '<td>' + cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF8,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 4  THEN '<td>' + cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF9,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 5  THEN '<td>' + cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF10,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 6  THEN '<td>' + cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF11,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 7  THEN '<td>' + cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF12,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 8  THEN '<td>' + cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF13,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 9  THEN '<td>' + cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF14,
           MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 10  THEN '<td>' + cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>' else '' END) as UF15
            FROM (SELECT INVOICE_REFERENCE_NUM,INVOICE_CHARGES,INVOICE_CREDITS,TRANSACTION_DATE,POSTED,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BT_ID ORDER BY BT_ID) AS rk        

FROM         Trans) AS Trans INNER JOIN
             Invoice AS Invoice ON Trans.INVOICE_REFERENCE_NUM = Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM LEFT OUTER JOIN
             Name AS Name ON Invoice.BT_ID = Name.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
             Org_Control AS Org_Control ON Invoice.ORG_CODE = Org_Control.OrgCode INNER JOIN
             Name_Address AS Name_Address ON Name.BILL_ADDRESS_NUM = Name_Address.ADDRESS_NUM WHERE     (Invoice.INVOICE_TYPE <'PP') AND
(Invoice.INVOICE_NUM <0) AND (Trans.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN
@FromDate AND GETDATE()) AND 
                      (Org_Control.OrgCode = @OrgCode) AND (Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES>0)
                       GROUP BY TRANSACTION_DATE,Trans.posted,Invoice.BT_ID,Name.COMPANY,
         Invoice.INVOICE_DATE,Name.COMPANY_RECORD,Name.COMPANY_SORT,Name.LAST_FIRST,Name.FULL_NAME,Name_Address.PURPOSE,Name.TITLE,Name_Address.FULL_ADDRESS,
         Invoice.INSTALL_BILL_DATE,Org_Control.OrgName,Org_Control.InvoiceAddress,Invoice.CUSTOMER_REFERENCE,Invoice.INVOICE_TYPE,Org_Control.OrgCode,Name.EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this query is quite complex, which I think is why you haven't had any answers up to now. There are some red flags here that (a) make it almost impossible to understand what the query is going, and (b) suggest a full rewrite using a totally different approach.

Among the warning signs:

1. Any query with 19 fields in the GROUP BY clause has lost its way somewhere along the line.
2. There is a mish-mash of INNER JOINS and LEFT JOINS (see discussion below)
3. Heavy use of copy-and-paste
4. Formatting/line-indentation is a mess

First, as to the LEFT JOINs:

1. You have included a LEFT JOIN to a table (Org_Control) that is referenced in the WHERE clause... since this table has to have a value in order to pass the WHERE criterion,  the LEFT JOIN adds nothing.
2. You have included a LEFT JOIN to the Name table, which is joined on BT_ID, which is a primary driver of your column arrangement. Could there really be rows in the query that don't match between the tables being joined?

Next, as to the overall approach to your query:

In SQL Server, I feel the clearest way to breakdown a bloated behemoth like this into manageable, understandable, testable chunks is with Common Table Expressions (CTEs). For a primer on CTEs, see https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml.

Also, it is possible that the simplest way to do what you want-- transforming rows of data from your resultset into columns-- is with a pivot table (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)

With those two building blocks in place, the way to get where you're going is this:

- Start from smaller, tested pieces (in this case, an INNER JOIN between Trans and Invoice),
- Then build on with lookup data like Name and Name_Address once you know the core is giving you the data that you want.

For your query, a workable framework might look something like this:

```
; WITH RowNumberedTrans AS (
  SELECT 
    INVOICE_REFERENCE_NUM, INVOICE_CHARGES, INVOICE_CREDITS, TRANSACTION_DATE, POSTED,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BT_ID ORDER BY BT_ID) AS rk
  FROM Trans
), UFLabeledTrans AS (
  SELECT 
    CASE rk
      WHEN 1 THEN 'UF6'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'UF7'
      -- etc
    END AS UFLabel,
    -- other fields
  FROM RowNumberedTrans
), TransactionsPerInvoice AS (
  SELECT 
    (
      '<td>' + 
      cast(Invoice.REFERENCE_NUM as varchar(10)) + '</td>' +
      cast(Invoice.DESCRIPTION as varchar(50)) + '</td>' + '$' +
      cast(Trans.INVOICE_CHARGES as varchar) +'</td>'
    ) AS UFValue,
    -- other fields
  FROM Invoice i
    INNER JOIN UFLabledTrans t ON i.REFERENCE_NUM = t.INVOICE
), InvoiceInfoInColumns AS (
  -- logic here to:
  -- * select from TransactionsPerInvoice
  -- * construct your pivot table spreading out UFValues computed above
  -- * do any grouping (should be on one or two fields at most)
  -- * etc.
), NameAddressLookup AS (
  -- INNER JOIN between Name and Name_Address
)
SELECT -- long list of columns
FROM TransactionsPerInvoice tpi 
  (LEFT? INNER?) JOIN NameAddressLookup nl ON tpi.BT_ID = nl.ID
```

Good luck; hope that's enough to get you started in the right direction.